# How to display an error message when TextInput field is empty?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm currently working on an mobile application in react-native ( actualy on the login page ).

I would like to display an error message below a TextInput when his field is empty.

To do this I'm trying to use the @react-hook-form library

I'm wrapping my TextInput into a Controller and I set up a "rules" propriety to "required" and the message I want to print but its not working...

```
<View>
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name="username"
    defaultValue=""
    rules={{
      required: { value: true, message: "Nom d'utilisateur nécessaire" },
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        
        <TextInput
          value={value}
          placeholder={'utilisateur'}
          autoFocus={true}
          onChangeText={(text: string) => {
            onChange(text);
            handleChangeText(text, 'login');
          }}
          onSubmitEditing={() => refPasswordInput.current?.focus()}
        />

    )}
  />
```

I already search everywhere but I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

{EDIT}

this is the updated component after the first answer :

```
<View>
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name="username"
    defaultValue=""
    rules={{
      required: { value: true, message: "Nom d'utilisateur nécessaire" },
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        
        <TextInput
          value={value}
          placeholder={'utilisateur'}
          autoFocus={true}
          onChangeText={(text: string) => {
            onChange(text);
            handleChangeText(text, 'login');
          }}
          onSubmitEditing={() => refPasswordInput.current?.focus()}
        />
       {errors.username && <Text>{errors.username.message}</Text>}
    )}
  />
</View>
```

and this is a screen of what I got : [image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the error message from the React Hook Form, you need to read the error object for each form field and display it under the TextInput.

In your case, the "username" field error can be accessed through `errors.username` object. If the field has any validation errors, it will have an object containing a 'message' field with your error message. You can use it to display the error when needed.

Here's how to modify your code to display the error message:

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
//...
const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

<View>
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name="username"
    defaultValue=""
    rules={{
      required: { value: true, message: "Nom d'utilisateur nécessaire" },
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <>
        <TextInput
          value={value}
          placeholder={'utilisateur'}
          autoFocus={true}
          onChangeText={(text: string) => {
            onChange(text);
            handleChangeText(text, 'login');
          }}
          onSubmitEditing={() => refPasswordInput.current?.focus()}
        />
        {errors.username && <Text>{errors.username.message}</Text>}
      </>
    )}
  />
</View>
```

In the example above, if the "username" field has an error (which it will if it is not filled out due to your rule), it will show an error message right below your TextInput. This error message comes from the rules you set for the field.

Comment: Well, firstly thanks for you quick answer.

I just did what you just wrote but its not displaying anything even if the field is empty, I will update my post to show you !